# "Google Apps Script version deployment" change - More than one active deployment - how to update an active deployment?

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications

I recently noticed that when I deploy a new version of web app, it gives me a new URL instead of using the old one. The problem is I use the web app as webhook, which is so annoying for me to replace the webhook URL every time I make some changes. Also, the old version doesn't get archived automatically when I deploy a new version. Is it a new policy? Is there any way to revert this setting?
**Note:** I'm using the new editor. But I find the old editor is also performing the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep the same web app URL, or the same project ID (if you shared your script as a library), use the "Manage deployments" option in the new code editor.

### Steps:

- click on "Manage deployments"
- select your existing deployment
- click on the edit / pencil button
- click on the Version dropdown
- click on "New version" in the dropdown
- click on the "Deploy" button

Don't click on the "New deployment" menu entry.

#### Reference:

- [Edit a versioned deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#edit_a_versioned_deployment)

Comment: I've tried to apply this procedure to a script which is integrated as a library and it only moves the edited deployment to archive and has no impact on the linked script.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I haven't been using Apps Script for a while now, so I don't know what the current situation is.