# New Google Apps Scripts IDE Deployment Issues

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, ide

I have a webapp that was created prior the new GAS IDE was launched. Recently I noticed that while using the new GAS IDE, if I save my changes and proceed to publish those through a new deployment with the tested application's latest code using the new IDE, the new app deployment was not the one being executed which I noticed by checking the execution logs which was still showing a previous version of the app deployment being run (I was on deployment/version 76 while the logs were showing that the execution code was done with version 74, which was months old).

I searched online and I couldn't find any reports of this issue.
is there something I should be doing to ensure that my webapp runs on the latest deployment as opposed to an old deployment version?

just in case you wonder, I did make sure I was publishing the exec version of my webapp when I tested the execution (link obtained from the new ide). I was not using a dev version or any other kind.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the webapp deployment versioning publishing issue fixed by switching back to the legacy editor and doing the republishing/deployment from there. After that, the code being executed on the execution log showed my latest deployment being run on the published webapp.

Weird, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Deploy > New deployment use Deploy > Manage Deployments, the click Edit and on the version dropdown, select New.

Related

- ["Google Apps Script version deployment" change - More than one active deployment - how to update an active deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66931059/1595451)

Comment: Thank you @Rubén, will give it a try, cheers!