# How to deploy a library version by replacing the old one in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries, version

I have a Google Apps script file containing some functions. A certain version of this script is assigned to many projects as a library. When I do some changes in the script file I want to deploy this new version to all the projects easily without having to change the assigned script version in every project. A similar question (["Google Apps Script version deployment" change - More than one active deployment - how to update an active deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931059/google-apps-script-version-deployment-change-more-than-one-active-deployment)) has an accepted answer that doesn't seem to work: When I follow this instructions it is still the former version of the script active and the one I've edited is then listed as archived.

What do I have to do in order to deploy changes?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, it will be best to make a request for this feature by following the steps in this [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback).

Comment: I think even if you were able to deploy in the way you are thinking, it wouldn't work. Because when you add a library to another apps script project, you have to choose the version you want to use, not the deployment.